# Failure to find ../****.h file qt5, C++ on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, header, qmake

I am running the qmake command in "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" but I get this error:

```
c:\Projects\Yenka\yenka\Software>qmake

Project MESSAGE: *** DEBUG ***

Project MESSAGE: Language:

Project MESSAGE: INSTALL is set to ./install

WARNING: Failure to find: ../falcon_precomp.h
```

It can't locate the .h C++ Header File, but the file is in the directory I have cd into under the falcon.pro file. Why is it not able to find the Header file?

I am new to building and a bit more detailed solution would be amazing if possible.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: The project was build originally using qt 5.5 for Mac OS, I am trying to build it on qt5.10 for Windows.

The falcon.pro file:

```
# Used by autobuild
# If you change the structure of this file please see build master
TEMPLATE = subdirs

include(config.pri)
CONFIG+= ordered

# see if we're in autobuild mode

# We use the variable KERNELDIR throughout all our project files but it can't
# be defined in config.pri because that could be included from project files
# at different places in the filesystem. See kernel.pri and domain.pri for
# their definitions of KERNELDIR ( which necessarily differ from this one ).
KERNELDIR = Kernel

autobuild {

    message("--- in autobuild mode ---")

    SUBDIRS += $$AB_DOMAINS\

    # print out all the things we're going to build
    message($$SUBDIRS)

    # build the unit tests
    # SUBDIRS += unittests

} else {

    SUBDIRS += $$KERNELDIR/core/licence/ccLG \
               $$KERNELDIR/core \
               $$KERNELDIR/ccUI \
               $$KERNELDIR/cc2D \
               $$KERNELDIR/cc3D \
               $$KERNELDIR/core/ccMigration \
               $$KERNELDIR/core/ccMigration/plugin \
               $$KERNELDIR/editor \
               $$KERNELDIR/application \
               $$KERNELDIR/bootstrap \
               $$KERNELDIR/3rdparty

    DOMAINDIR = Domains
    DOMAINS = \
               $$DOMAINDIR/equation \
               $$DOMAINDIR/presentation \
               $$DOMAINDIR/data \
               $$DOMAINDIR/probability \
               $$DOMAINDIR/maths \
               $$DOMAINDIR/flowcharts \
               $$DOMAINDIR/human3D \
               $$DOMAINDIR/electronics \
               $$DOMAINDIR/motion3D \
               $$DOMAINDIR/motion \
               $$DOMAINDIR/waves \
               $$DOMAINDIR/optics \
               $$DOMAINDIR/chemistry

   SUBDIRS += $$DOMAINS
}

# mark product package files to be searched for translatable strings

TRANSLATIONS += \
    translation.ts
```

The Falcon_precomp.h file:

```
#ifndef FALCON_PRECOMP_H
#define FALCON_PRECOMP_H

/* Falcon Pre-compiled headers

   Please only include STABLE headers here
 */

/* C includes here */

/* C++ includes here */
#if defined __cplusplus

/** Note: The following include should always be first to
    avoid un-necessary compiler warnings
 */
#include "core/core_include.h"

// us
#include "cc/Assert.h"
#include "ccModel/Document.h"
#include "ccModel/Part.h"
#include "ccModel/Model.h"
#include "ccModel/Node.h"
#include "ccModel/Pad.h"
#include "ccModel/Part.h"
#include "cc/Point.h"
#include "ccModel/Property.h"
#include "cc/Resource.h"
#include "ccModel/Validator.h"
#include "cc/Value.h"
#include "cc/Vector.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

// qt
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QImage>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QWidget>

#endif

#endif // FALCON_PRECOMP_H
```

The config.pri file:

```
CONFIG +=  warn_on thread qt

CONFIG -= debug_and_release

# This command forces to go into release mode, for some reason release
# does not work at the moment.
# CONFIG += forcerelease

# On the current release, symbol visibility is default, as some of
# the symbols are not found otherwise during cross compilation and
# linking.
CONFIG += unhide
DEFINES += FINAL_RELEASE
DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG

# Set region-specific and demo build options
DEFINES += $$(CC_LANG) $$(CC_DEMO) $$(FINAL_RELEASE)

# Since NodeImpl header uses qdom.h, Qt XML module is needed by everything.
QT += xml 
# Qt Network module is needed on Mac almost everywhere.
mac: QT += network

forcerelease {
    CONFIG -= debug
    win32 {
        CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe
        CONFIG -= embed_manifest_dll
    }
    DEFINES -= DEBUG
}

# debug is default setting for everything except autobuild and forcerelease
autobuild {
    CONFIG -= debug
    win32 {
        CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe
        CONFIG -= embed_manifest_dll
    }
    DEFINES -= DEBUG
} else {
    !forcerelease {
        CONFIG += debug
        DEFINES += DEBUG
        DEFINES -= DEBUG
    }
}

debug {
    message( "*** DEBUG ***" )
    message( "Language: $$(CC_LANG)" )
}
else {
    message( "*** RELEASE $$(CC_DEMO) $$(FINAL_RELEASE) ***" )
    message( "Language: $$(CC_LANG)" )
}


DEFINES += QT_CLEAN_NAMESPACE

no_emotionfx {
    message( "config.pri: NO_EMOTIONFX is defined" )
    DEFINES += NO_EMOTIONFX
}

win32 {
    autobuild {
        # Go easy on the release build for now...
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = /W3 /WX /wd4305
    } else { 
        # Turn on all warnings and treat treat them as errors. 
        # Well, all except C4127 as QT throws this up all the time. 
        # ... and C4512 ( assignment operators cannot be generated )
        # ... and C4100 ( unused formal parameter )
        # ... and C4709 ( comma in array index - incorrectly flags 
        #                 functions with multiple arguments in index )
        # ... and C4305 ( truncation of double to float, happens in lots of osg code )
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = /Wall /WX /wd4127 /wd4512 /wd4100 /wd4709 /wd4305
    }

    # message( $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE )
    # Release build:
      # -O2: Creates the fastest code in the majority of cases. 
      # -Oy-: Prevent frame pointer optimisation to improve stack walking
    # -Zi: Create PDB file containing debug symbols
    # -MD: (from default Qt flags)
    # -MP: parallel compilation switch
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O2 -Zi -MD -MP4 /Oy-

    # Remove access control from the manifest so Vista will allow 
    # us to write to the virtual store.
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /DEBUG /MANIFESTUAC:NO

} else {
    # Remove those given to us by default to suppress qmake -Wall warnings
    # If this changes then then qmake -Wall will let us know provided we
    # stick to a staight assignment rather than += when we set our own.
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall -W
    # lots of warnings, supress unknown pragma warnings, make warnings errors
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wunused -Werror

    # GCC 4.x
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-non-virtual-dtor

    # devbuilder compiler flags a few things not seen elsewhere
    mac {
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-format-security -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-c++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-parentheses-equality
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-potentially-evaluated-expression -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-constant-logical-operand
        # GCC 4.0.1 incorrectly warns about control paths in some functions
        # not returning values when in fact the control path is actually
        # unreachable. Until we upgrade to something like 4.1 or better we
        # just disable the warning.
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-return-type
    }
}

mac {
    # Force precompiled headers on the mac
    #CONFIG += precompile_header

    # build fat binaries of everything. No easy way to target
    # the 10.3.9 SDK on PPC only
    autobuild {
        CONFIG += x86 ppc
    }
    QMAKE_MAC_SDK=macosx10.11
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG=-gdwarf-2
}

# Precompiled headers for platforms which support this
# WARNING: Windows builds currently depend on this to work. Not sure why. The
# build goes fine without them but the app. crashes when parts are dragged on.
#!autobuild {
    precompile_header: PRECOMPILED_HEADER = ../falcon_precomp.h
#}

# The top directory in the source code hierarchy
TOPDIR = ../..

autobuild {
    DEFINES += BUILD_ID=\"\\\"$$AB_BUILD_ID\\\"\"
    DEFINES += AB_PDB_DIR=\"\\\"$$AB_PDB_DIR\\\"\"
    INSTALL += $$AB_INSTALL
    win32 {
        INCLUDEPATH += $$CPPUNIT_INCLUDE
        LIBS += $$CPPUNIT_LIB
    }
} else {
    # not in autobuild - use a default install location
    INSTALL = ./install
}

message( "INSTALL is set to $$INSTALL" )

INST_DIR = $$TOPDIR/$$INSTALL
INST_SOFTWARE_DIR = $$INST_DIR/Software

#message( "INST_SOFTWARE_DIR is set to $$INST_SOFTWARE_DIR" ) 

debug : OBJECTS_DIR = _obj
debug : MOC_DIR = _moc
!debug : OBJECTS_DIR = _obj_r
!debug : MOC_DIR = _moc_r


win32 {
    LIB = win32
    LIB_EXT = *.dll
}
unix {
    LIB = linux-i386
    LIB_EXT = *.so
}
mac {
    LIB = MacOS
    LIB_EXT = *.dylib
}

# override copy method for install stage.
# see Qt\3.3.2\qmake\generators\win32\winmakefile.cpp for more of these
# undocumented gems
win32 {
    QMAKE_INSTALL_FILE = xcopy /Y /R /K /Q
    QMAKE_INSTALL_DIR = xcopy /E /Y /R /K /Q /I
}


quantify {
    win32 {
        QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /fixed:no /incremental:no
        QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += /fixed:no /incremental:no
        DEFINES += QUANTIFY
    }
}

unix{
    gprof {
        CONFIG += unhide
        message( "Compiling for gprof..." )
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pg
        QMAKE_LFLAGS += -pg
    }

    unhide {
        message( "Unhiding symbols..." )
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -fvisibility=default
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fvisibility=default
    } else {
        # By default we mark all symbols hidden. As with Windows this is
        # overridden in code with the various EXPORT macros.
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -fvisibility=hidden
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fvisibility=hidden
    }
}

win32 {
    # VS2008 reports a warning when using crt functions for which there is a new secure version
    DEFINES += _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
}

DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG
DEFINES -= DEBUG

# uncomment this to get char* descriptions set on NodeImpl and
# PropertyImpl.  Easy to see in the debugger.
# DEFINES += CC_MODEL_DEBUG_STRINGS
```

Comment: You should add more details: 1) the directory source tree; 2) the qmake .pro file; 3) the line where the falcon_precomp.h file is included

Comment: @S.Monteleone I have added the the content of both the qmake .pro file and the C++ Header file in my original post. Both files are in the same directory c::/projects/falcon1/software

Comment: Post your `config.pri` file.

Comment: @user3606329  I have added the config.pri file.

Comment: Change `precompile_header: PRECOMPILED_HEADER = ../falcon_precomp.h` to `precompile_header: PRECOMPILED_HEADER = falcon_precomp.h` if it's in your same directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me so much time, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message:

> WARNING: Failure to find: ../falcon_precomp.h

means QMake cannot find the header file: falcon_precomp.h in directory above: ../

Please make sure that the falcon_precomp.h file is in directory above (../) and rerun the qmake command.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. The falcon_precomp.h is in the directory that I have cd into and it is in the same directory as the .pro file. This is why this is confusing me.

Comment: QMake looks for falcon_precomp.h file in different location, here the above one: ../, than your .pro file.  Apparently it is how the qmake was configured. You may either try to modify the qmake file  (so it searches for that header where it is really located) or move the header file to the location where it looks for it. Another option would be to add INCLUDEPATH += ../ to your qmake configuration.